# configure squid3 to set up a web proxy in ubuntu12.04

Tags: ubuntu, squid, proxy-server

I am in a LAN and have to use a proxy given to access the web in a very limited way. I can't even use google, github.com or SE sites. However I can use ssh to log into a server(also in LAN), which I have root access so basically I can do anything I want with it. So I was thinking that maybe I could use that server as a proxy so I can visit sites through it.

I tested it using ssh -vT git@github.com which gave a proper response. And In my computer I can't do this.

Also I tried downloading something from the gun.org using wget, which can't be done in my computer too. And it succeeded on that server.

I don't know if that's enough to say that this server have full access to the Internet. But I assumed so and I installed squid3 on it. After trying some while， I failed to get it working.

I got this after I run `squid3 -k parse`

```
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing Configuration File: /etc/squid3/squid.conf (depth 0)
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl manager proto cache_object
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl localnet src 10.1.0.0/16   # RFC1918 possible internal network
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl SSL_ports port 443
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 80     # http
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 21     # ftp
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 443        # https
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 70     # gopher
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 210        # wais
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 280        # http-mgmt
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 488        # gss-http
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 591        # filemaker
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 777        # multiling http
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: acl CONNECT method CONNECT
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: http_port 3128 transparent vhost vport
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Starting Authentication on port [::]:3128
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Disabling Authentication on port [::]:3128 (interception enabled)
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Disabling IPv6 on port [::]:3128 (interception enabled)
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: cache_mem 1000 MB
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: cache_swap_low 90
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: refresh_pattern ^ftp:      1440    20% 10080
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: refresh_pattern ^gopher:   1440    0%  1440
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|?) 0 0%  0
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: refresh_pattern .      0   20% 4320
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: ipcache_high 95
2012/07/06 21:45:18| Processing: http_access allow all
```

I deleted some allow and deny rules and added http_access allow all so that all the request would be allowed.

After configuring my computer, I got this error:

```
Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.
```

And the log in the server showed that my TCP requests had all been denied.

So, first of all, is what I am trying to do achievable? If so, how to configure the squid in the server so that I use it as a proxy to surf the Internet?

My computer and the server both run Ubuntu11.04.

And server IP:10.1.242.26 my IP:10.1.232.23

Thanks for any help~

Answer (score 0):

Strange you do have "allow all"... could you post the squid.conf?

Or Try this:

Change "http_access allow all" to "http_access deny all" and before that line add the allow rules you need, for example: http_access allow localnet